# batch get csv values and save them into variables for further use

Tags: csv, batch-file

I want to extract the values of an file like this:

```
4564,cde0
7578,Kernel
123465,Performer
INFO,Kernel
```

*I thought putting the data into a csv file would be the easiest option, but if there is an easier way to get the values in variables, I am open for suggestions. I will have way more than four lines...*

I want to use the values:
From line 1 I need 4564 and cde0 in separate variables.
Put them in my script and than continue with line two and so on.

I have found a several threats who deal with columns and by now I have the following code:

```
for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%a in (test.csv) do (@echo %%a %%b)
```

But that just shows me the content without the ",".

Is there any way to go through a line and put the two values into two variables?

If so I think the easiest way to go through a csv file would be a loop where I extract the values into variables, use them and continue with the next line, but as I am not very familiar with batch I don't know if that is the best way to do so.

Thank you

Comment: Depending on what you need to do next with the variables it might be possible to avoid using temporary "arrays" (batch files don't have arrays so you'll end up with lots of numbered variables instead) and process the data in one loop. How about adding a ps to the question with a short summary of the subsequent/overall task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this case, multi-dimensional array will do the trick. Since batch don't have array feature, but we can make it ourself! Just like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set var1=0

for /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%a in (text.csv) do (
    set var2=0
    set array[!var1!][!var2!]=%%a
    set /a var2+=1
    set array[!var1!][!var2!]=%%b
    set /a var1+=1
)

echo First column, First element: %array[0][0]%
echo First column, Second element: %array[0][1]%
echo Second column, First element: %array[1][0]%
echo Second column, Second element: %array[1][1]%

pause >nul
```

Let me briefly expalin what's going on here. Multi-dimensional array is an array containing one or more arrays. The most common array looks like `array[0]`, which indicates the 1st element since the element counts from 0.

While multi-dimensional array like `array[0][0]` indicates the 1st array's 1st array (may sounds confusing). Think of `array`**[0]**`[0]` is the line, `array[0]`**[0]** is the column, so `array[1][2]` indicates the 2nd line, 3rd column. (*Draw a table and practice)

Comment: Thank you that was very useful! Unfortunately I can not up vote you as I don't have enough reputation...

Answer (score 1):

```
C:>type test.csv
4564,cde0
7578,Kernel
123465,Performer
INFO,Kernel

C:>type g.bat
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /F "tokens=1-2 delims=," %%a in (test.csv) do (
    set FIRST_VALUE=%%a
    set SECOND_VALUE=%%b

    echo FIRST_VALUE is !FIRST_VALUE! and SECOND_VALUE is !SECOND_VALUE!
)

C:>g.bat
FIRST_VALUE is 4564 and SECOND_VALUE is cde0
FIRST_VALUE is 7578 and SECOND_VALUE is Kernel
FIRST_VALUE is 123465 and SECOND_VALUE is Performer
FIRST_VALUE is INFO and SECOND_VALUE is Kernel
```